# ¿Como unir respuesta split python?

Tags: python

tengo un script en `python 2.7` el cual me conecto a telnet y ejecuto un comando ya hago todo ese proceso lo que deseo hacer es poder unir mejor los resultados estoy utilizando `split`

Código:

```
import telnetlib
import re

def espera_prompt():
    return tn.read_until("\n>")

HOST    = "123.589.3.212"
CRED    = "juan soporte"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

espera_prompt()
tn.write(CRED  + "\r\n")

numeros     = ['0123456789']

emergencia  = ['130','131','132','133','134','135','136','137','138','139','1400','1402','1403','1404','1405','1406','1407',
                '1408', '1409','1411','1412','1413','1414','1415','1416','1418','1419','1420','1421','1424','1451','143','147',
                '149']

mi_path = "fichero.txt"

contador = 0

with open(mi_path, 'a+') as f:
    for i in numeros:
        for j in emergencia:
            VAR = "traver l {} {} ainres icsx cont nt"
            FINAL = VAR.format(i,j)
            espera_prompt()
            tn.write(FINAL + "\r\n")
            respuesta = espera_prompt()
            #print respuesta
            trozos = respuesta.split(">")
            for trozo in trozos:
                tratamiento = re.findall("TREATMENT IS: ([A-Z]+)", trozo)
                if tratamiento:
                    print "%02d Tratamiento: %s" % (contador, tratamiento[0])
                datos = re.findall("^\\d\\s+[A-Z0-9]+\\s+\\d+\\s+ST\\s+$", trozo, re.M)
                for d in datos:
                    partes = d.split()
                    print "  ", partes[1], partes[2]
                contador += 1
            f.write(partes[1])
            tn.write("exit\r\n")
salida = tn.read_all()
print salida
```

Respuesta:

```
00 Tratamiento: GNCT
   VIN21T7BVINA032 130
   MOVI1L7BVINA032 326317322611164
02 Tratamiento: GNCT
   VIN21T7BVINA032 131
   MOVI1L7BVINA032 326317322665560
04 Tratamiento: GNCT
   VIN21T7BVINA032 132
06 Tratamiento: GNCT
   VIN21T7BVINA032 133
08 Tratamiento: GNCT
   VIN21T7BVINA032 134
   EPHO1L7BVINA032 326322322189891
   VIN21T7BVINA032 326322322189891
10 Tratamiento: GNCT
   VIN21T7BVINA032 135
   EPHO1L7BVINA032 326322323132059
12 Tratamiento: GNCT
   VIN21T7BVINA032 136
   MOVI1L7BVINA032 136
14 Tratamiento: GNCT
   VIN21T7BVINA032 137
   MOVI1L7BVINA032 137
16 Tratamiento: GNCT
   VIN21T7BVINA032 138
   ENTE1P7BVINA032 326823229768613
   VIN21T7BVINA032 326823229768613
18 Tratamiento: GNCT
   VIN21T7BVINA032 139
   EPHO1L7BVINA032 326322323132292
   VIN21T7BVINA032 326322323132292
20 Tratamiento: VACT
22 Tratamiento: VACT
24 Tratamiento: VACT
26 Tratamiento: GNCT
   MOVI1L7BVINA032 1404
28 Tratamiento: VACT
30 Tratamiento: VACT
32 Tratamiento: GNCT
   MOVI1L7BVINA032 1407
34 Tratamiento: VACT
36 Tratamiento: VACT
38 Tratamiento: VACT
40 Tratamiento: GNCT
   VIN21T7BVINA032 1412
42 Tratamiento: VACT
44 Tratamiento: VACT
46 Tratamiento: VACT
48 Tratamiento: VACT
50 Tratamiento: VACT
52 Tratamiento: VACT
54 Tratamiento: VACT
56 Tratamiento: VACT
58 Tratamiento: VACT
60 Tratamiento: VACT
62 Tratamiento: VACT
64 Tratamiento: GNCT
   VIN21T7BVINA032 147
   VIN21T7BVINA032 326320225051147
66 Tratamiento: GNCT
   VIN21T7BVINA032 149
   VIN21T7BVINA032 326320225051149
```

Lo que deseo obtener es el siguiente resultado:

```
Tratamiento: GNCT => VIN21T7BVINA032 => 149 => VIN21T7BVINA032 => 326320225051149
```

Si vemos este ejemplo no vienen todas las variables por ende las que no vengan que estén vacías pero.. es importante guardar el `"VACT"`

```
22 Tratamiento: VACT
```

Un array para así luego poder crear `mi_path = "fichero.txt"` con todas las respuesta ya que estos resultados los necesito enviar a una base de datos

Comment: No se si me aclaro, quieres un "array" (algún contenedor como una lista, diccionario, etc) o simplemente cadenas de la forma que muestras para guardarlas como lineas del fichero, es decir para tu ejemplo las tres últimas cadenas (lineas del fichero) serían `"62 Tratamiento: VACT"`, 
`"64 Tratamiento: GNCT => VIN21T7BVINA032 => 147 => VIN21T7BVINA032 => 326320225051147"` y
`"66 Tratamiento: GNCT => VIN21T7BVINA032 => 149 => VIN21T7BVINA032 => 326320225051149"`

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es poder darle un mejor formato al resultado para así se me haga mas fácil recorrerlo y almacenarlo en la base de datos. No se si me explico ?

Comment: @FJSevilla O de que manera me recomiendas hacer ?

Answer (score 0):

Pues si todo lo que necesitas es formato podrias hacer lo siguiente:

```py
    line_to_print = list()
    if tratamiento:
        line_to_print.append("%02d Tratamiento: %s" % (contador, tratamiento[0]))
    for d in datos:
        partes = d.split()
        line_to_print = line_to_print + partes[1:3]
    print " => ".join(line_to_print)
    contador += 1
```

Me pareció mas fácil de controlar y debuggear tener una sola vez la function print que estar agregando prints mediante llegan los datos. Espero que te ayude!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prueba.py", line 38, in <module>
    for d in datos:
NameError: name 'datos' is not defined